# Extract the title from each section in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document formatted in sections, each section has a title (of format "overskrift 1"). That's quite the norm there.

I created a macro to export each section as a separate pdf document. That part works great. I wish that the name/title of the section be the name of the file.

Here is my current code :

```
Dim strName As String
strName = InputBox(Prompt:="Save To:", Title:="Save file to:", Default:=ActiveDocument.Path)

If strName = vbNullString Then
Exit Sub
Else

End If

Dim intSectionsNr As Integer
intSectionsNr = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count - 1

Dim intValue1 As Integer
Dim intValue2 As Integer
Dim intSection As Integer

For intSection = 1 To intSectionsNr
    intValue1 = ActiveDocument.Sections(intSection).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber) + 1
    intValue2 = ActiveDocument.Sections(intSection + 1).Range.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

    Dim titre As String

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        strName & "\" & intSection & ".pdf", _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportFromTo, From:=intValue1, To:=intValue2, Item:= _
        wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=False, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=True
        
Next intSection
```

How do I do so that the title/heading can be used in the filename ?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little helper function:

It will return the text of the first paragraph of the section with style Heading 1:

```vb
Public Function getTitleOfSection(s As Section) As String
Dim p As Paragraph
For Each p In s.Range.Paragraphs
    If p.Style = ThisDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1) Then
        With p.Range
            .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
            getTitleOfSection = .Text
        End With
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Then in your code you can use the function like this:

`titre = getTitleOfSection(ActiveDocument.Sections(intSection))`

Comment: My heading here is not the first paragraph of the section. So it does not work.

Comment: I updated the answer: it now looks for the first paragraph with heading 1 style. If you are not using the default Heading 1 style you can check for `p.Style = "overskrift 1"`

Comment: Your solution looks to be good.

Except - I don't know why - the text selected is always empty / void.

I truly don't understand. Thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the title into your titre variable using a substring operation on the text of the document.  Watch out intValue2 needs set to the length of the text for the last section otherwise I think ActiveDocument.Sections(intSection + 1) will cause an exception.  It looks like titre is the whole section so you will need to take the first line.   Lastly when you get the scetion title you will need to strip out any invalid filename characters.